# Cannot load or save txt. file

Tags: python, pycharm, save, load

I wrote a code but apparently It does not save and load to my txt. file. I would greatly appreciate if you took a look into my code and told me what's wrong because I am having really hard time figuring it out myself. I didnt use pickle, as It was creating encoding related difficulties so I tried to find the other way around it and all which saves into my txt. file is "None". Thank you in advance.

```
def savedata(x):
    play_again = input("Are you willing to save existing progress? Y/N")
    if (play_again == "Y") or (play_again == "y"):
        print("Saving progress...")
        file = open('adam_malysz.txt', 'w')
        file.write(str(x))
        file.close()
        print("Your file has been called - adam_malysz.txt")
        print("Progress has been successfully saved.")
    else:
        print("Returning to main menu")
def arrayfancy():
    num1 = int(input("Select size of an array: "))
    value = []
    for i in range(num1):
        value.append(random.randint(1, 99))
    print("Printing data...")
    print(value)
    print("Sorting Array...")
    bubblesort(value)
    print(value)
    print("Average value is: ")
    print(statistics.mean(value))
    print("Minimum value is: ")
    print(min(value))
    print("Maximum value is: ")
    print(max(value))
    print("Your data has been successfully printed")

    if choice == 1:
       savedata(arrayfancy())
```

Comment: `arrayfancy` is not returning any string. It is just printing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `arrayfancy()` has no `return` statement, so it returns None when it reach the end of the function block. `savedata(x)` then successfully write "None" to your file.

You can add `return value` at the end of `arrayfancy()`, this will solve your issue.

---

I tested the code bellow and I get the text file containing the array.

```py
def savedata(x):
    play_again = input("Are you willing to save existing progress? Y/N")
    if (play_again == "Y") or (play_again == "y"):
        print("Saving progress...")
        file = open('adam_malysz.txt', 'w')
        file.write(str(x))
        file.close()
        print("Your file has been called - adam_malysz.txt")
        print("Progress has been successfully saved.")
    else:
        print("Returning to main menu")

def arrayfancy():
    num1 = int(input("Select size of an array: "))
    value = []
    for i in range(num1):
        value.append(random.randint(1, 99))
    print("Printing data...")
    print(value)
    print("Sorting Array...")
    bubblesort(value)
    print(value)
    print("Average value is: ")
    print(statistics.mean(value))
    print("Minimum value is: ")
    print(min(value))
    print("Maximum value is: ")
    print(max(value))
    print("Your data has been successfully printed")
    return value

if choice == 1:
    savedata(arrayfancy())
```

Comment: oh my god, how obvious... Thank you so much for your help. May you have at least 10 beautiful red headed children. All the best buddy.

Comment: @Filipxg I am glad to have been helpful. As my answer seems to address fully your question, you could accept it :)